# Get old values from datastore through endpoint

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I'm facing a little problem with my datastore on google app engine.
Here the background.

I've defined my projecton Google.
-> Version A : for my android application
-> Version B : for my website (administration)

When I put some data through Version B, I can the new values in DataStore Viewer (after few seconds). If I change values from DataStore Viewer, I can see changes in Version B.

But in my Android Application I'm not able to see any change. I've to restart my instance or redeployed my Endpoints to catch update.

What I miss ?

I'm using AppEngine 1.9.0 (and it didn't work on previous version).

Thanks for your help !